# How do I kill a drone operator by blowing up their drone?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

One of the Assault Challenges in Splinter Cell Blacklist is to do the following:

> #### Backfire
>
> Kill 2 drone operators by blowing up their drones.

Should sound simple right?  Well... drone operators are heavily armored with a helmet.  Heavily armored enemies are immune to explosions (as far as I can tell).  An explosion merely knocks them off their feet and they just get back up again.  Anyone see the problem here?

**How the heck am I supposed to kill these guys with one of their drones?**

It's frustrating enough trying to find one of them easily accessible. I'm even going using Rookie difficulty just to make my job easier.  And still, even when I shoot the one he drops right at his feet, he never dies...  Knocking his helmet off doesn't seem to make a difference either, he just flies away further than usual.  One managed to die this way but it didn't even count... what gives?

Comment: I dont know the mission or achviment for blowing up the operator. But I kill them by first shooting off their helmet on my own - since it seems like the helmet is the key to their protection. I can either blow them up, or take them out with another shot to the head. Note that your weapon need to have so much damage and force to take their helmet off. I use a sniperrifel for this.

Comment: Killing them in general isn't the problem. They're actually pretty easy to take out since they just sit there. Blowing them up (with or without their helmet) just doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Ill try to look around for answerers. Its a very good question! Going to test it out as well.

Comment: I finally got it. I think it was the choice of weaponry. You should be using a loud gun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get credited for this challenge.  It isn't *the* most straightforward challenge to get so you'll just have to tough it out.

I think the thing that made the big difference is that when you destroy their drones, it has to:

1. Be shot at.  (so no grenades or other gadgets)
2. Be shot with a loud weapon.  (so no silent weapons)

Probably one of the easiest places to get it is in one of **Charlie's** 4E missions, **Pakistani Embassy** and get to the **13th wave**.

In this wave, there will be many drone operators just sending their army of drones at you along with the usual horde of regulars, armoreds, dogs etc.  It doesn't matter what difficulty, but it will make things easier if done on Rookie.

There will be many different entry points for the drone operators.  However the one where I think you'll have the easiest time dealing with is the one on the upper level across from the embassy which looks like a bombed out building.  Here's a screenshot of me just hanging out of the windows:

[image: just outside the area]

Of all their entry points, this has the most cover for you to hide behind.  A total of two drone operators will spawn there throughout the wave so whatever you do, don't kill them until the end that way you can kill the two required for the challenge together.

First step is to kill everyone else until the two drone operators are the last ones left alive.  The second won't spawn until much later in the wave so don't worry if you don't see him, he'll be there.

When everyone else is finally dead, clear out all of the drones that are still active in the map.  That way the operators will send out new ones when you're ready.

With all drones gone, wait until they are not alerted so the drones aren't going crazy fast too soon.  Take cover behind the wall where they are camping.  They shouldn't see you and it should give you a good position to take a quick shot at their drones as they are launched.

[image: waiting spot]
<sup><sub>(this was taken *after* the wave so you can't see them now)</sub></sup>

Depending on the direction they launch their drones, you might have to face the other opening.

Then from here, you just gotta play the waiting game.  Wait until they launch their drone and shoot it once to stop it.  You shouldn't shoot it again to kill it because it will take multiple drone explosions to eventually kill them.  Although they are heavily armored, they will eventually die after direct hits of enough explosions.  I would stop maybe 2-3 drones at their feet before considering blowing them up.  It might take more but you'll get it eventually.

When you're ready, shoot a disabled drone to get it to blow up.  The operators will probably right next to eachother and the chain reaction of explosions should be enough to finally kill them both.  If not, just repeat the process until they finally die and you should get the challenge.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't a "you only have to accomplish once" challenge, it has multiple levels.  The second, you need to kill a total of 10.  And I suspect the third will be 25 or 50.